# Prolog helloWorld not working

Tags: prolog

Silly question, but I'm trying to get this simple Prolog program working. I have written other small Prolog programs with no problem, but this one is giving me trouble:

```
test :- write 'test1234 test1234',nl,halt.
```

That's it. The file is saved as `adventure1.pl`. It is loaded into  SWI-Prolog on Ubuntu with the command line option:

```
prolog -s adventure1.pl
```

When loaded into the Prolog interpreter I enter the following:

```
start.
```

However, Prolog says `undefined procedure: test/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)`.  What is the error here, is it somthing really simple. I wrote this because I have example programs that use a predecate named start which displays text, yet I can't even get this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
write 'test1234 test1234'
```

is a syntax error, as SWI-Prolog clearly indicates:

```
ERROR: /tmp/adventure1.pl:2:10: Syntax error: Operator expected
```

It should be

```
write('test1234 test1234')
```

(Of course, that won't solve the problem of *start* not working, because you've defined *test*.)

Comment: Aww snap, missing brackets! Thanks, I feel stupid right now.  My version of SWI prolog recently installed from the default Ubuntu repository did not give a more meaningful error like you got.

Comment: @AndrewS There are two errors and you definitely got them both. The one larsmans is talking about is the syntax error you didn't see because it was printed above the startup banner because you used `prolog -s adverture1.pl` instead of `[adventure1].` from within Prolog. The error you saw is what lars is referring to when he said `start` won't work because you defined `test`.